# In MS Excel cell format, How to change the default time duration from "number of days" to "number of minutes"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, date-time

In MS excel if I set a cell format as time (e.g. [h]:mm:ss) and then if I type any number `N` in that cell, MS excel assume that number as **number of days** since `1st Jan 1900 00:00:00`. Is it possible to change this behavior and let MS excel interpret that `N` as **number of minutes** since `1st Jan 1900 00:00:00`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change the behavior - the integer portion of an Excel data value is the days in 1/1/1900, as you explain, and the decimal fraction denotes hours and minutes. Why not compute the minutes directly and then display them as you wish with a custom number format?

Comment: The easy option would be dividing the content of a helper cell by 1440.